# Angular - Como enviar um objeto dentro de um model em um método POST?

Tags: json, angular, http, post

Boa tarde, estou tendo um problema para enviar um POST para uma API publicada por conta de um dos parâmetros esperados ser um objeto, de maneira que o json esperado está da seguinte forma :

```
{"Cargo": string,
 "idFuncionario": 0,
 "idCadastro": 0,
  "cadastro": {
                "idCadastro": 0,
                "nome": "string",
                 "razao": "string",
                  "documento": "string"
              }

"dtAtualizacao": "2019-02-22T17:32:38.049Z",
}
```

o único valor que chega nulo na API é o do objeto "cadastro", tentei de diversas formas enviá-lo, sem êxito, uma vez que estou iniciando no angular agora, qualquer ajuda seria de extremo proveito, o método post em service está da seguinte maneira:

```
    postFuncionario(funcionario : Funcionario){   

      try {
          var body = JSON.stringify(funcionario);
            var headerOptions = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
            var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({method : RequestMethod.Post,headers : headerOptions});
            return this.http.post(this.localUrl+'Create'
            ,body,
            requestOptions).map(x => x.json());              
        }

      catch (error) {
            return Observable.throw(error)
          }

    }
```

o método onSubmit , em componente:

```
 onSubmit(form:NgForm){


if (form.value.idFuncionario   == null) {
  this.service.postFuncionario(this.form.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.toastr.success('Novo registro gravado com sucesso!', 'Funcionário Cadastrado')
      console.log(this.service.funcionario )
      console.log(this.form.value)
      console.log(form.value.idFuncionario)
      this.resetForm()
    })
}
```

exemplo do databinding no template:

```
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="idFuncionario"  placeholder="ID Funcionário"
                 [(ngModel)]="service.funcionario.idFuncionario" value="{{service.funcionario?.idFuncionario}}">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" #nome="ngModel"
                [(ngModel)]="service.funcionario.cadastro.nome" value="{{service.funcionario?.cadastro.nome}}">
```

por fim, o model:

```
 import {Cadastro} from './cadastro.model'


 export class Funcionario {

 Cargo : string
 idFuncionario : number
 cadastro : Cadastro
 }
```

é isto, qualquer ajuda seria otimo!

Comment: no caso, estou utilizando o angular 7 com todos packages atualizados

Answer (score 0):

no caso está faltando uma vírgula:

```
{"Cargo": string,
 "idFuncionario": 0,
 "idCadastro": 0,
  "cadastro": {
                "idCadastro": 0,
                "nome": "string",
                 "razao": "string",
                  "documento": "string"
              }
 aqui ,
"dtAtualizacao": "2019-02-22T17:32:38.049Z",
}
```

Comment: e ainda tem uma vírgula no final desnecessária.